# Filtering via a many to many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, many-to-many

There are lots of "has_many" rails questions on stack overflow, but nothing that has been what I need. I have three models: Users, OrganizationUsers, and Organizations. They look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_users #the model relating User and Organization
  has_many :organizations, through: :organization_users
```

And

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_users
  has_many :users, through: :organization_users
end
```

And

```
class OrganizationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

What I am trying to do with a great amount of frustration is to only display users to current user if they are an admin AND the admin's organization matches the user's organization. So I will give an example of what I tried that did not work to give you the idea (from users_controller.rb):

```
admin_users << User.where(current_user.organizations.all.include? :organization )
```

Obviously this is not working, but I think it shows what I am trying to do. Adding to the complications is the fact that **I would really like to use paginate**, which apparently does not like taking a strait up array as a parameter so I was hoping to do this purely with filters if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define an "admin_user". Is it a user where `user.role == "admin"? In addition, you said "matches a user's organization". Since a user can have many organizations, should that be plural? I.E., should one of the admin's organizations match one of the user's organizations?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you are defining admins, but assuming a simple admin boolean on the User model, you can query for all admins in the current user's organization like this:

```
User.includes(:organizations).where('organization_users.organization_id' => current_user.organization_ids, :admin => true)
```

Comment: You can use ` :organization_users => {:organizations_id => current_user. organization_ids} `

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
OrganizationUser.where(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:user).where(user: {admin: true}).includes(:user).map(&:user)
```

1. Get all the `OrganizationUser` matching current user, to get all its organizations
2. Joins on the `users` table and select only admins (I assumed there's a boolean in the `users` table, change if it's different)
3. Get the `User` object of each `OrganizationUser` filtered previoulsy